# Take sum of input textbox columns based on drop down value selected

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table, css-selectors

I am a beginner in Jquery. Need your help on the below problem.
I have a html table with 3 columns and 3 rows. Each column has a header example col1,col2 and col3. There is a column approval status with values- Approved, approval pending and not approved. I have to take the sum of the values entered by user in each text box for each column. Currently in my code I'm taking that sum for each column. But I want to take the sum only when approval status is "Approved". I'm not sure which event handler to use as the user can either first enter the number or approval status random order. Thank you!

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
input {display: block;}
input.total {margin-top: 30px;}
[class*="total"] {
  background: #ffff00;
  p.double {border-style: double;}
}
.none{
display:none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table class="aa">
<th> Approval status</th>
<th>col1</th>
<th>col2</th>
<th>col3</th>
<tr>
<td id="selectBox1">
<select id = "myList1">
<option value = "1">Choose Approval Status</option>
<option value = "2">Approved</option>
<option value = "3">Approval Pending</option>
<option value = "4">Not Approved</option>
</select>
</td>
<td> <input type="text" class="qty1" value="" /> </td>
<td> <input type="text" class="qty2" value="" /> </td>
<td> <input type="text" class="qty3" value="" /> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="selectBox2">
<select id = "myList2">
<option value = "1">Choose Approval Status</option>
<option value = "2">Approved</option>
<option value = "3">Approval Pending</option>
<option value = "4">Not Approved</option>
</select>
</td>
<td> <input type="text" class="qty1" value="" /> </td>
<td> <input type="text" class="qty2" value="" /> </td>
<td> <input type="text" class="qty3" value="" /> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>  <input type="text" class="none" value="" /></td>
<td>  <input type="text" class="total1" value="" /> </td>
<td>  <input type="text" class="total2" value="" /> </td>
<td>  <input type="text" class="total3" value="" /> </td>
 </tr>
</table>
<script>
$(document).on("change", ".qty1", function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".qty1").each(function(){
        sum += +$(this).val();
    });
    $(".total1").val("total:" + sum);
});
$(document).on("change", ".qty2", function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".qty2").each(function(){
        sum += +$(this).val();
    });
    $(".total2").val("total:" + sum);
});
$(document).on("change", ".qty3", function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".qty3").each(function(){
        sum += +$(this).val();
    });
    $(".total3").val("total:" + sum);
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you use `#selectBox` and `#myList` multiple times? ID should be **unique**

Comment: It seems more logical to just have 1 'Approval Status' select element. Please elaborate as to why there are 3. If there needs to be 3, when should it sum? When all 3 are approved?

Comment: check my answer hope you'll find it helpful

Comment: @Rob Moll: I have edited the code.sorry for confusion. The last dropdown was extra. For each row which has textbox input by user will have dropdown and user will select if that is approved or not. Then I need to show the sum in last box only for textbox which has approved status. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have way too much code in your snippet. By reducing it you can make it re-usable. Also, you don't really need all these `id` and `class`-attributes to govern your script.

The following script can be applied on a table of any size.

```js
$("table.aa").on("change input",ev=>            // act on both: "change" and "input"
  $("table.aa tr:last td:gt(0)").each((i,td)=>  // go over each result input field
    $('input',td).val(                          // and set its value to:
      $("table.aa tr")                          // find all rows ...
       .filter((j,tr)=>$("select",tr).val()==2) // but only those having a select==2
       .find("input:eq("+i+")").toArray()       // take i-th input in each row
       .reduce((a,c)=>+c.value+a,0)             // and accumulate all values
    ) 
  )
)
```

```css
input {display: block;}
.total {
  background: #ffff00;
  p.double {border-style: double;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="aa">
<th> Approval status</th>
<th>col1</th>
<th>col2</th>
<th>col3</th>
<tr>
<td>
<select>
<option value = "1">Choose Approval Status</option>
<option value = "2">Approved</option>
<option value = "3">Approval Pending</option>
<option value = "4">Not Approved</option>
</select>
</td>
<td> <input type="text"/> </td>
<td> <input type="text"/> </td>
<td> <input type="text"/> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<select>
<option value = "1">Choose Approval Status</option>
<option value = "2">Approved</option>
<option value = "3">Approval Pending</option>
<option value = "4">Not Approved</option>
</select>
</td>
<td> <input type="text"/> </td>
<td> <input type="text"/> </td>
<td> <input type="text"/> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<select>
<option value = "1">Choose Approval Status</option>
<option value = "2">Approved</option>
<option value = "3">Approval Pending</option>
<option value = "4">Not Approved</option>
</select>
</td>
<td> <input type="text"/> </td>
<td> <input type="text"/> </td>
<td> <input type="text"/> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>  </td>
<td>  <input type="text" class="total" value="" /> </td>
<td>  <input type="text" class="total" value="" /> </td>
<td>  <input type="text" class="total" value="" /> </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you help. This works exactly as needed. Your  response was very useful.

Comment: Yeah, that is the good thing with jQuery: you almost always know when you are on the right path, because then you "write less, do more." ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the select's values from number to the same text as the one in `innerHTML` and
use if statement like `if($('#myList1').val() == 'Approved')` so that the sum will be calculated if the if statement is true only

```js
$(document).on('change', '.qty1', () => {
  if ($('#myList1').val() == 'Approved') {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".qty1").each(function() {
      sum += +$(this).val();
    });
    $(".total1").val("total:" + sum);
  }
});
$(document).on('change', '.qty2', () => {
  if ($('#myList2').val() == 'Approved') {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".qty2").each(function() {
      sum += +$(this).val();
    });
    $(".total2").val("total:" + sum);
  }
});
$(document).on('change', '.qty3', () => {
  if ($('#myList3').val() == 'Approved') {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".qty3").each(function() {
      sum += +$(this).val();
    });
    $(".total3").val("total:" + sum);
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
}

input.total {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

[class*="total"] {
  background: #ffff00;
  p.double {
    border-style: double;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="aa">
  <th> Approval status</th>
  <th>col1</th>
  <th>col2</th>
  <th>col3</th>
  <tr>
    <td id="selectBox">
      <select id="myList1">
        <option value="none" selected>Choose Approval Status</option>
        <option value="Approved">Approved</option>
        <option value="Approval Pending">Approval Pending</option>
        <option value="Not Approved">Not Approved</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td> <input type="text" class="qty1" value="" /> </td>
    <td> <input type="text" class="qty2" value="" /> </td>
    <td> <input type="text" class="qty3" value="" /> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="selectBox">
      <select id="myList2">
        <option value="none">Choose Approval Status</option>
        <option value="Approved">Approved</option>
        <option value="Approval Pending">Approval Pending</option>
        <option value="Not Pending">Not Approved</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td> <input type="text" class="qty1" value="" /> </td>
    <td> <input type="text" class="qty2" value="" /> </td>
    <td> <input type="text" class="qty3" value="" /> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="selectBox">
      <select id="myList3">
        <option value="none">Choose Approval Status</option>
        <option value="Approved">Approved</option>
        <option value="Approval Pending">Approval Pending</option>
        <option value="Not Pending">Not Approved</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td> <input type="text" class="total1" value="" /> </td>
    <td> <input type="text" class="total2" value="" /> </td>
    <td> <input type="text" class="total3" value="" /> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. The code doesn't work as expected; its taking the sum for all irrespective of the status selected and not just approved ones.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution for your requirement, it will output the sum of values based on the status of each row with the help of final row dropdown value change.

```js
$(".finalState").on("change", function() {
            if($(this).val() == 2) {
              var t1 = t2 = t3 = 0;
              var tTR = $(this).parents("tbody").find("tr");
              tTR.each(function(){
                if(!$(this).hasClass("total-row") && $(this).find(".myList").val()==2){
                  var qty1 = $(this).find(".qty1").val();
                  if(!isNaN(qty1) && qty1 !== null && qty1 !== '' ){
                    t1 = (parseFloat(t1) + parseFloat($(this).find(".qty1").val()));
                  }
                  
                  var qty2 = $(this).find(".qty2").val();
                  if(!isNaN(qty2) && qty2 !== null && qty2 !== '' ){
                    t2 = (parseFloat(t2) + parseFloat($(this).find(".qty2").val()));
                  }
                  
                  var qty3 = $(this).find(".qty3").val();
                  if(!isNaN(qty3) && qty3 !== null && qty3 !== '' ){
                    t3 = (parseFloat(t3) + parseFloat($(this).find(".qty3").val()));
                  }
                }
              });
            } else if($(this).val() == 3) {
              var t1 = t2 = t3 = 0;
              var tTR = $(this).parents("tbody").find("tr");
              tTR.each(function(){
                if(!$(this).hasClass("total-row") && $(this).find(".myList").val()==3){
                  var qty1 = $(this).find(".qty1").val();
                  if(!isNaN(qty1) && qty1 !== null && qty1 !== '' ){
                    t1 = (parseFloat(t1) + parseFloat($(this).find(".qty1").val()));
                  }
                  
                  var qty2 = $(this).find(".qty2").val();
                  if(!isNaN(qty2) && qty2 !== null && qty2 !== '' ){
                    t2 = (parseFloat(t2) + parseFloat($(this).find(".qty2").val()));
                  }
                  
                  var qty3 = $(this).find(".qty3").val();
                  if(!isNaN(qty3) && qty3 !== null && qty3 !== '' ){
                    t3 = (parseFloat(t3) + parseFloat($(this).find(".qty3").val()));
                  }
                }
              });
            } else if($(this).val() == 4){
              var t1 = t2 = t3 = 0;
              var tTR = $(this).parents("tbody").find("tr");
              tTR.each(function(){
                if(!$(this).hasClass("total-row") && $(this).find(".myList").val()==4){
                  var qty1 = $(this).find(".qty1").val();
                  if(!isNaN(qty1) && qty1 !== null && qty1 !== '' ){
                    t1 = (parseFloat(t1) + parseFloat($(this).find(".qty1").val()));
                  }
                  
                  var qty2 = $(this).find(".qty2").val();
                  if(!isNaN(qty2) && qty2 !== null && qty2 !== '' ){
                    t2 = (parseFloat(t2) + parseFloat($(this).find(".qty2").val()));
                  }
                  
                  var qty3 = $(this).find(".qty3").val();
                  if(!isNaN(qty3) && qty3 !== null && qty3 !== '' ){
                    t3 = (parseFloat(t3) + parseFloat($(this).find(".qty3").val()));
                  }
                }
              });
            }
            $(".total1").val(t1);
            $(".total2").val(t2);
            $(".total3").val(t3);
        });
```

```css
input {display: block;}
        input.total {margin-top: 30px;}
        [class*="total"] {
        background: #ffff00;
        p.double {border-style: double;}
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table class="aa">
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>col1</th>
            <th>col2</th>
            <th>col3</th>
            <th>Approval status</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> <input type="text" class="qty1" value="" /> </td>
            <td> <input type="text" class="qty2" value="" /> </td>
            <td> <input type="text" class="qty3" value="" /> </td>
            <td class="selectBox">
                <select class= "myList">
                    <option value = "1">Choose Approval Status</option>
                    <option value = "2">Approved</option>
                    <option value = "3">Approval Pending</option>
                    <option value = "4">Not Approved</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <input type="text" class="qty1" value="" /> </td>
            <td> <input type="text" class="qty2" value="" /> </td>
            <td> <input type="text" class="qty3" value="" /> </td>
            <td class="selectBox">
                <select class="myList">
                    <option value = "1">Choose Approval Status</option>
                    <option value = "2">Approved</option>
                    <option value = "3">Approval Pending</option>
                    <option value = "4">Not Approved</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <input type="text" class="qty1" value="" /> </td>
            <td> <input type="text" class="qty2" value="" /> </td>
            <td> <input type="text" class="qty3" value="" /> </td>
            <td class="selectBox">
                <select class="myList">
                    <option value = "1">Choose Approval Status</option>
                    <option value = "2">Approved</option>
                    <option value = "3">Approval Pending</option>
                    <option value = "4">Not Approved</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="total-row">
            <td>  <input type="text" class="total1" value="" /> </td>
            <td>  <input type="text" class="total2" value="" /> </td>
            <td>  <input type="text" class="total3" value="" /> </td>
            <td class="selectBox">
                <select class = "myList finalState">
                    <option value = "1">Choose Approval Status</option>
                    <option value = "2">Approved</option>
                    <option value = "3">Approval Pending</option>
                    <option value = "4">Not Approved</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```